# Navigation drop downs sitting behind the video created with mediaelement.js - how to fix?

Tags: z-index, mediaelement.js

The page in question is sitting at:

```
newnetpartners.inspirationincbeta.co.uk/voice.php
```

The issue we are having is with the drop down on the navigation falling behind the video (created with `mediaelements.js`). 
So far the `z-index` on both the site's css and the video's css have been set as they should be but still the problem is occuring.

Has anyone had the same issues as this and found a fix for it, or does anyone have any ideas on what could be causing it.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I dont see the page in question!

Comment: MediaelementJS manipulates the DOM. Probably it helps when you inspect the rendered page with Firebug for example.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. have had a play about and come up with a conclusion. Have 1 more issue which has come up, have altered the question above it anyone can help

Comment: Good to know it helped. Generally, on Stackoverflow you should not alter questions to a new meaning. Instead, ask a new question.

Comment: The drop down you mention, do you talk about the translation selector, or is there something else, i am not seeing?